# Join two Collections with LINQ with Contains operator

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have following two classes

```
Class C
{
public Guid Id{get;set;}
public string Type{get;set;}
}

Class D
{
  public List<Guid> CIds {get;set;}
  public string Type {get;set;}
}

 var D_Collection = new List<D>();
 var C_Collection = new List<C>();

 // SET The C_Collection.Type On the Basis of D_Collection
 // If C.Id exist in D.CIds then C.Type = D.Type
```

I want to Set C.Type bases on the Criteria Given above in Comments

I tried following but it's not working

```
 var temp = (from x in D_Collection
                        from y in C_Collection
                        where x.CIds.Contains(y.Id)
                        select new {
                               Id = y.Id,
                               Type = x.Type
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want to actually join the two lists together into one `List`?

Comment: Anything that lets me set C.Type on the basis of D.Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple and iterative, and there may well be a better solution. However it will do what you need.

```
public void SetTypeOnCList(List<D> dlist, List<C> clist)
{
    clist.ForEach(c =>
    {
        var dobj = dlist.FirstOrDefault(d => d.CIds.Contains(c.Id));
        if (dobj != null)
        {
            c.Type = dobj.Type;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: True, poor naming convention right there :P. And this is why we have peer session refactoring ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

public IQueryable GetData(string DataType)
{

```
 IQueryable<DatabaseObject> dbData = (
    from t in db.All<DatabaseObject>().Where(e => e.Category == TransType)
    join e in WebHelpers.LocalList
    on t.Type equals e.Type
    orderby t.DateOccurred descending
    select t
); 

return dbData;
```

}

Comment: It's List<Guid> in one collection and Guid in another how equals will work here?

Answer (score 1):

You can's use `Enumerable.Join` if the join condition is a `Contains` on another collection. You could use `SelectMany`(`from`...`from` in query syntax) on the `Guid`-collection first though:

```
var allDIDs = from d in D_Collection from id in d.CIds select new { dObj = d, id };
var cToUpdate = from c in C_Collection
                join dID in allDIDs
                on c.Id equals dID.id
                select new { cObj = c, dType = dID.dObj.Type };

foreach (var x in cToUpdate.Distinct())
    x.cObj.Type = x.dType;
```

or use this query:

```
var cToUpdate = C_Collection
    .Select(c => new { 
        cObj = c, 
        FirstmatchingIdType = D_Collection
          .FirstOrDefault(d => d.CIds.Contains(c.Id))?.Type 
     })
    .Where(x => x.FirstmatchingIdType != null);

foreach(var x in cToUpdate)
    x.cObj.Type = x.FirstmatchingIdType;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler to do this:

```cs
var c_comparisons = D_Collection.SelectMany(x => x.CIds.Select(y => new C { Id = y, Type = x.Type }));

foreach (var comparison in c_comparisons)
{
    var c = C_Collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == comparison.Id);

    if (c != null)
    {
        c.Type = comparison.Type;
    }
}
```